# How to set the variable to boolean in typescript according to my code?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

The Error Comes Like This: `type boolean is not assignable to type any[]`

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {GithubService} from '../services/github.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.component.html'
})
export class ProfileComponent {
    user: any[];
    repos: any[];
    username: string;
    constructor(private _githubService:GithubService){
        this.user = false; //....!!!Here The Error Comes!!!...
    }

    searchUser(){
       this._githubService.updateUser(this.username);

       this._githubService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
            //console.log(user);
            this.user = user;
        })

        this._githubService.getRepos().subscribe(repos => {
            this.repos = repos;
        })
    }
}
```

I did this this.user: `boolean = false`, but did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to provide multiple types to a variable using pipe bar

```
export class ProfileComponent {
     users : any[]|boolean;
}
```

Or if your content is mutable to multiple types then use **any** as type

```
export class ProfileComponent {
     users : any;
}
```